# Is Microsoft discontinuing the "Visual Studio Installer" or not?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, installshield

Is Microsoft discontinuing the "Visual Studio Installer" or not? Somewhere I remember reading that they were, in favor of going with InstallShield LE. But I can't find this on MS's site anywhere. Does anyone else have any info on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be the case. Check the announcement at the top of the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/threads).

> With InstallShield available, the
>   Visual Studio Installer project types
>   will not be available in future
>   versions of Visual Studio. To preserve
>   existing customer investments in
>   Visual Studio Installer projects,
>   Microsoft will continue to support the
>   Visual Studio Installer projects
>   feature that shipped with Visual
>   Studio 2010 and below as per our
>   product life-cycle strategy. For more
>   information, see Expanded Microsoft
>   Support Lifecycle Policy for Business
>   & Development Products.